# Where should I keep track of my window handles when writing a windows desktop application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to write my first windows desktop application in c++, but I'm very new to this, and I don't know how I should be keeping track of my window handles for child windows.

I've run into a few issues with losing my window handles, for example:

When accepting [WM_HSCROLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-hscroll#parameters) messages from multiple trackbars, the specific trackbar is identified in the message by the lParam, which contains a handle to the trackbar window... but if I don't store my window handles, then I don't know which trackbar the message has come from!

Should I be storing them in a global variable? This doesn't seem very safe.

Should I create a struct, or class, to wrap the parent window and store important variables like window handles? If so, how would I go about this?

Comment: Maybe wrap your window in a class.

Comment: ***Should I be storing them in a global variable? This doesn't seem very safe.*** A global variable is usually not a good choice.

Comment: @drescherjm disagree with all three of your comments.

Comment: Nowhere. All the window handles are traversable through GetDlgItem() and functions like that. You mostly want to save top-level windows or use `GWLP_USERDATA` with `SetWindowLongPtr()`.

Comment: You can associate arbitrary data with a window handle, `SetWindowLongPtr(win, GWLP_USERDATA, ptr)`. You could for instance store a pointer to a C++ object representing that window.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis could you elaborate on that please? I thought that```GeDlgItem()``` required me to know the ID of the child window before I could get its handle. How would I know the ID of my child window if I haven't stored it anywhere?

Comment: The ID is static, it might be hardcoded to your app (or to the resource editor).

Comment: if you set meaningful IDs, use `int id = GetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_ID );` and `switch` on `id`.

Answer (score 3):

Window handles should be tracked in locations that make sense for the particular window. For example, if your program is such that it will only ever create a single instance of a main window class then storing that HWND probably isn't needed at all (an object storing state for the main window yes but not the HWND itself).

If that main window creates child windows (such as the mentioned track bars) then the track bar HWNDs would be stored as part of that main object state.

Really this is no different than any other program architecture problem, you need to design your program such that all needed data is exposed where it is needed but try to limit that exposure to only where it is in fact needed.

Comment: How can I store the trackbar HWNDs as part of the main object? Do I need to make a wrapper object for the main window, and store the child HWNDs within that? Or is there a more simple way to do it?

Answer (score -2):

Let's start with the very beginning.

Functions return result for a reason. If you ignoring a result of an API function, you are doing something wrong right now! It doesn't matter what the API function is, if there is a result returned, you should not discard it. It can be an object needed for further use or an error code, or something equally useful. And of course, window handles are very useful objects which you should not discard.

Now, once you got the handle and decided to keep it around (as you should) the question is **how**. The truth is, wrapping it in a class or not is a secondary decision. The best way to store the window handles would be to put them in some sort of a dynamic container. For example, `std::vector`.

The last, but not the least, is a question on how to access this container of handles from message processing function. One of the easiest ways (although not the most elegant) would be to make this vector a global variable. Than any message handler routing will have an easy access to it.

Comment: So I should just have a big vector of all my window handles at the start of my document? How do I keep track of which handle is for which window?

Comment: @JohnnyMayhew What do you mean by 'which' window? Handle **is** a window.

Comment: If, for example, I wanted to know which trackbar in particular a WM_HSCROLL message had come from, in order to process the message properly and carry out the right functions.

Comment: In case of trackbar, you can assign GWLP_ID to them, or use dialog functionality if creating them from static resource will work for you. Then WM_HSCROLL will have lparam == trackbar handle. You can get back ID assigned for this handle, that's how you know message origin.

Comment: Window handles aren't objects. They are values, that reference objects. Discarding those values (after having them checked against an error value, and possibly made sure that the window is visible) is fine, and common practice. In fact, it's rare that you *need* to keep window handles around. Most of the information can be retained by using compile-time constants, and assigning those as control IDs. With the exception of popup windows, every window has a control ID.

Comment: @IInspectable every variable in C++ is an object.

Comment: That's an opinion that won't be shared by many. Regardless, this doesn't change the fact, that this proposed answer is fairly misleading. Storing the return value of `CreateWindowEx` is rarely needed. The most prominent example is creating dialogs from resources. The dialog manager will happily throw away every single window handle it receives with a single exception. In doing so this does not at all impact the proper functioning of the dialog created. Which just goes to prove: Storing every single window handle is not at all required, which is in conflict with this proposed answer.

Comment: @IInspectable that is unquestionable fact. You can educate yourself by reading C++ standard.